# Visual Studio 2017 "The Diagnostic Tools failed unexpectedly." Error

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio version 15.8.9, I was experiencing several issues:

- Intellitrace was enabled but not working (the Step Backward and Step Forward buttons remained grayed out).
- I no longer saw PerfTips in my code while debugging.
- I saw an error in the Diagnostic Tools window.

With respect to the last item, I saw a "The diagnostic tools failed unexpectedly" error in the Diagnostic Tools window while running an application in debug mode.

To try to solve the diagnostic tools issue as a first step, I had reviewed and verified all the usual items:

- Tools | Options | Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging was checked.
- Showing PerfTips was enabled in Tools | Options.
- I was running the latest VS version.
- I had shut down all running instances of Visual Studio and re-started the IDE.
- I had rebooted the machine.

Nothing worked. Googling produced a number of hits (primarily for VS 2015), but none of those articles worked--and there were some useless tips there involving changes to the registry or deleting .suo files. Don't waste your time with those as they are unlikely to help if you see this issue in VS 2017.

Instead, try my solution below. It solved the Diagnostic Tools error and brought back the PerfTips display as well as Intellitrace functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run the Visual Studio Installer.
2. Click **Modify** under the Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 item.
3. Click **Individual components** at the top of the page.
4. Scroll to the **Debugging and testing** section.
5. Uncheck if checked the following items (leave unchecked if already unchecked):

   - .NET profiling tools
   - Intellitrace
   - Snapshot Debugger
   - Testing tools core features
6. Click **Modify** and wait.

When that process has finished, no need to restart or reboot. Click **Modify** again, go back to **Individual components** and check the following:

- .NET profiling tools
- Intellitrace
- Snapshot Debugger (optional)
- Testing tools core features

When the process has completed, your diagnostic tools window should work, PerfTips should appear (if set to show during debugging), and Intellitrace (if activated) should work.

Comment: unfortunately, this did not work. But thank you.

Comment: What version and edition of VS are you running?

Comment: VS 2019. Well, it did work today morning (!), but chose to quit just before noon (!!). Sigh. I will check tomorrow, maybe I have a chance a few hours after a reboot (although I tried a lot of reboots the last days... ;))